# how to pass data from jquery to php, to send message on gmail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

hello just need to send message on gmail.
Form submit should be implemented using jQuery.

i think i cant pass data from jquery to php.

without jquery file message is sending on gmail but when i include jquery on html it says that message was sent successfully but nothing appears on gmail

this is main PHP file

```
<?php
require 'Sendmail.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
            <label>Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
            <label>Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
            <label>message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        <a href="index.php">Sign Up</a>
        <button type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Send message">Send message</button>
    </form>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ContactValidation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is JQUERY file

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(e){
        var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
        if(valid){
            var firstname   = $('#firstname').val();
            var lastname    = $('#lastname').val();
            var email       = $('#email').val();
            var subject     = $('#subject').val();
            var message     = $('#message').val();
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            e.preventDefault();

            if (firstname == "" || lastname == "" || email== "" || subject == "" || message == ""){
                Swal.fire({
                    'title': 'Errors',
                    'text': 'All fields are compulsory',
                    'type': 'error'
                })
            }
            else {
                if (firstname.length>=64 || firstname.match(/[^\w\s]/gi)) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        'title': 'error',
                        'text': 'Please enter a valid firstname',
                        'type': 'error'
                    })
                }
                else if (lastname.length>=64 || lastname.match(/[^\w\s]/gi)) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        'title': 'error',
                        'text': 'Please enter a valid lastname',
                        'type': 'error'
                    })
                }
                else if (!email.match(regex)){
                    Swal.fire({
                        'title': 'error',
                        'text': 'Please enter a valid email',
                        'type': 'error'
                    })
                }
                else if (subject.length>=64){
                    Swal.fire({
                        'title': 'error',
                        'text': 'Subject must contain less than 64 character',
                        'type': 'error'
                    })
                }
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Sendmail.php',
                        data: {firstname: firstname,lastname: lastname,email: email, subject:subject, message:message},
                        success: function(data){
                            Swal.fire({
                                'title': 'Successful',
                                'text': data,
                                'type': 'success'
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and this is PHP file which send message on gmail

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sub = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = 'g_chkuaseli@cu.edu.ge';
    $subject = "Subject:  " . $sub ;
    $subject2 = "Copy of your subject:  " . $sub;
    $message = $firstname . $lastname . " wrote the following message: \n\n" . $message;
    $message2 = "Copy of the message: " . $message;
    $headers = "From: " .$email;
    $headers2= "From: " . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($email,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);

}

echo "Email sent! Thank you " . $firstname . ", We will contact you shortly.";
```

Comment: your action contains a if condition if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ and in your ajax request you are not sending it just change the object to {firstname: firstname,lastname: lastname,email: email, subject:subject, message:message,"submit":"send"} and hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @BlackXero you're doing the following check:

`if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

This is usually used when you submit a form directly from html or php to the Sendmail.php. So in this case you don't need that check.

Also in this example your form is still trying to submit somewhere due to you adding the method and action attributes for your form. In this case you could (probably should) remove those as well as add the `e.preventDefault()` to the beginning of your button click function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include this require 'Sendmail.php' as form is submitting using ajax.
and write your message i.e. 'email send' in if condition